# How to set cellType "General" to "Number" using NPOI

Tags: npoi

I have simple cell and formula cell in both of case i want to set cell type number but it takes default general type. Plz help me how can i set cell type general to number type.

Answer (score 2):

We can change  cell format in following way:

```
Dim CellFormat As HSSFCellStyle = HSSFWorkbook.CreateCellStyle()
CellFormat.DataFormat = &H29
```

Here &H29 is direct value of specific format if we want to get format then can follow:

```
Dim CellFormat As HSSFCellStyle = HSSFWorkbook.CreateCellStyle()
CellFormat.DataFormat = HSSFDataFormat.GetBuiltinFormat("#,##0")
```